# Scala (JavaFX) sbt-assembly does not package images/photos

Tags: java, scala, javafx, sbt, sbt-assembly

The following code perfectly works inside Eclipse IDE. But, SBT does not assemble the image when packages a jar.

```
val myImg = new ImageView("/assets/images/sample.jpg")
val imgLabel = new Label("", myImg)
```

Comment: `sbt-assembly` will include resources from `src/main/resources` folder into a Jar, not `assets` folder - it does not know about it. Can you move those files into `src/main/resources` or you are forced to use `assets` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sbt-assembly` will take resources from `src/main/resources` folder into a Jar, not from `assets` folder - it does not know about it at all. 
Try to do next:

1) Add `assets` folder as resource folder. In your `build.sbt` add next line:

```
resourceDirectory := baseDirectory.value / "assets"
```

2) Load image from the resources, not from the file file path of your project:

```
val url: URL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResource("images/sample.jpg")
val myImg = new ImageView("images/sample.jpg")
```

Hope this help!